# Convert JavaScript Date-Time Format

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to get the date data from the database as "dd.mm.mm.yyyy HH:mm".
How can I convert this data with Javascript?

Normally the date data comes as follows,

`2023-08-14T15:20:59.659667+03:00`

The format I want it to be,

`14.08.2023 20:59`

Js code side,

```
tablerow = $('<tr/>');
tablerow.append(`<td class="border-bottom-0">${value.createDate}</td>`);
```

Can you help me?
Thanks,

I did not encounter any errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```js
    // Input date string 
    const inputDate = '2023-08-14T15:20:59.659667+03:00'; // Declare this to get Date from your DB. 
    
    // Create a new Date object from the input date string
    const date = new Date(inputDate);

    // Format the date as "dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm"
    const formattedDate = `${('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}.${('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}.${date.getFullYear()} ${('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2)}:${('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)}`;

    console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you, 
This works to bring the current date, but how can I convert the format of the date in the database?

This is the format in the database `2023-08-14T15:20:59.659667+03:00`

Comment: I just edited the code

Comment: If your input Date from Databse isnt String, you have to replace it using this code:
const inputDate = String(dataFromTheServer)

Comment: Thank you very much, I can get it in the format I want now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to format the date:

```js
function formatDate(dateToFormat) {
  const date = new Date(dateToFormat);

  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = String(date.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
  const day = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
  const hours = date.getHours();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes();

  return `${day}.${month}.${year} ${hours}:${minutes}`;
}
```

Note: **dateToFormat** should be in string format